# Data Imputation Without Ground-truth

Tags: missing-data, model-evaluation, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

recently I am dealing with a project of data imputation. I use the probabilistic imputation (multiple imputation) methods. As is known, the real data do not contain the **REAL** values for the missing positions (aka. ground-truth).

I have read some papers and the authors generated the artificial missing indices so that they could calculate the quantitative errors (MSE, MAE etc.). My question is, when dealing with the real dataset, how could we determine/evaluate the appropriate imputations? Is there any statistical method? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *My question is, when dealing with the real dataset, how could we determine/evaluate the appropriate imputations?*---What do you mean? This seems a bit vague. Maybe you can elaborate a bit with some more specifics.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Hi, I am dealing with stock market data imputations, especially for holiday time. So generally, there is not trading information during these days.